# Keeping track of “abuse” (or other) flags?

Tags: discussion, comments, policy, flagging

Do PSE mods (or SE more generally) keep track of comments deleted for “ harassment, bigotry, or abuse”.  Should they? If yes, are there consequences for repeat offenders?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no *automatic* consequence for repeated flags for rudeness or abuse. However, there are automatic flags raised when particular users accrue a number of these flags in a certain timeframe, prompting moderators to review the behaviour in question. This system is not perfect, so if you observe a pattern of rudeness and you want to make certain the moderators are aware of it, please do raise a custom flag explaining this pattern.

Users that repeatedly show such behaviour will often receive a message pointing this out to them, which can also include a temporary suspension, depending on the severity. The length of such suspensions increases with repeated infractions, see e.g. [this post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2759/50583) - the usual pattern is 7 days for the first issue, 30 days for the second, and a year for the third.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications.  I was just curious: nothing specific in mind.